# AWS - Override DeleteOnTermination in an AMI through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm using a preconfigured Mongo AMI which has Provisionned IOPS Volume. I'm creating the instance throught CloudFormation.
Their default configuration is to not delete them when terminating the Instance.

I'd like to override that setting, but where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DeleteOnTermination](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html#cfn-ec2-blockdev-template-deleteontermination) is an embedded property of the [Amazon Elastic Block Store Block Device Property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html), which is in turn an embedded property of the [Amazon EC2 Block Device Mapping Property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html) property. You do not need to specify the latter at all when satisfied with the block device mapping that is persisted in the AMI itself, however, you can still do so if you want to apply any changes like the one at hand (or remove a volume all together etc.), in which case you'll basically need to replicate the entire existing mapping and apply your customization on top of it.

- The *Examples* section within [Amazon EC2 Block Device Mapping Property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html) illustrates the basic syntax, there are also two more complete snippets in context available, see [EC2 Block Device Mapping Examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html#scenario-ec2-bdm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DeletionPolicy` attribute on just about any AWS resource managed by CloudFormation.

The `DeletionPolicy` attribute enables you to specify how AWS CloudFormation handles the resource deletion. By adding a `DeletionPolicy` to a resource, you can control how AWS CloudFormation handles the resource when its stack is deleted. By default, AWS CloudFormation deletes the resource if it has no `DeletionPolicy` attribute. You can specify *Retain* for AWS CloudFormation to leave a resource without deleting it. For resources that support snapshots, such as AWS::RDS::DBInstance and AWS::EC2::Volume, you can specify *Snapshot* for AWS CloudFormation to create a snapshot before deleting the resource.

[See more about the attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html).